# How do I change slider color in react-awesome-slider

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to change the background color of a react-awesome-slider. I've tried to change styles.css, and also tried to add a new CSS file, but nothing seems to work. I've been trying to find an answer for hours by now, but nothing seems to work.

I'm a beginner in web development, so I'm sorry if my question seems unnecessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your slider tile with a div and style the div with a background as desired.

```
<div className='page'>
  <Tile/>
</div>
```

It took me a while to figure it out too.